# Sprint/T-Mobile merger includes 0.13 cash equivalent

Tags: stock-exchanges

The sprint/tmobile exchange rate is 9.75, but what does the remaining 0.13 cash equivalent mean which is also part of the deal?

Comment: Can you post a link to the news article where you read this information?

Comment: Ben - when I searched to find details, I found the linked question.it seemed fresh enough. If terms changed, we can edit the answer there.